# Check if tree element is prepreterminal

Tags: java, python, tree, nltk, stanford-nlp

I am moving a java implementation of a syntactic analysis tool into python. The java implementation is using `edu.stanford.nlp.trees.Trees` but on python i am using nltk trees.

I am using [this](https://github.com/dasmith/stanford-corenlp-python) way to access the stanford parser from python. At certain points in the processing of sentences i have to check if the items in the parsed tree are prepreterminals and this is how its done with java `if (tree.isPrePreTerminal())` however that method does not seem to be implemented in the nltk trees.

Is there a way of doing this within nltk without implementing the code myself. Since the java source is quite extensive i will probably run to incompatibilities again, is there an other package i can use to better parse stanford syntax trees in python?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse stanford trees into python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26710981/parse-stanford-trees-into-python)

Comment: @justhalf Yes it almost is, i dont know how to close them though,
here is the answer if you are looking for it btw 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26752970/treebank-style-tree-parser-python