# Treebank-style tree parser python

Tags: java, python, nlp, nltk

Recently i have been trying to parse syntactic trees returned by the [stanford parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml) in python. I have been trying to do that with nltk `tree = Tree.parse(result['sentences'][0]['parsetree'])` and the parsing succeeds but the tree class of nltk offers very few processing methods. I will need methods like `tree.isPrePreTerminal()` which are not included from what i understand. I found [this](http://nlp.stanford.edu/~mcclosky/software/PyInputTree/) alternative but it seems that it doesnt like 64bit architectures and it gives me this error `ImportError: InputTree/_InputTree.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32` even though i compiled with the `-m64` flag. 
I have been looking into this the last 2 days, if you know a way to make the above module to work with 64bit systems or an alternate library or at least a good nltk.tree documentation so that i implement the methods myself please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `PyInputTree` is no longer maintained. However, the `InputTree` class from the `Charniak` parser lives on in wrapped form as the [`Tree` class in BLLIP Parser](https://github.com/BLLIP/bllip-parser/blob/master/README-python.rst#the-tree-class). It doesn't  implement `isPrePreTerminal()` but here's one way to do it:

```
import bllipparser

def is_prepreterminal(node):
    """Returns True iff all children of this node are preterminals."""
    subtrees = node.subtrees()
    return len(subtrees) > 0 and \
        all(subtree.is_preterminal() for subtree in subtrees)

# testing code
tree = bllipparser.Tree('(S1 (S (NP (DT This)) (VP (VBZ is) (NP (DT a) (ADJP (RB fairly) (JJ simple)) (NN parse) (NN tree))) (. .)))')
for subtree in tree.all_subtrees():
    print subtree, is_prepreterminal(subtree)
```

See [`bllipparser`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bllipparser) on PyPI for more information.